# Need All MySQL Results with value UserID or NULL - No additional UserIDs

Tags: mysql

When a user is on my website, and they click 'Add' or 'Remove' item... The Add or Remove message is the opposite of what it should be SOMETIMES. For example, when you click a button, it will change colors. It will be gray is value is NOT 'Y' and red if it is 'Y'. Sometimes it is reversed.  This is because of the query below GROUP BY clause which I am using to avoid duplicates (which happens in the collection table, because each user adds a new record to this Intersection table). Without the group by clause, there are many duplicates.

```
SELECT a.AmiiboID, a.Name, a.ImageURL, c.Favorited, c.Collected, c.WishList, c.UserID
FROM Amiibo a
LEFT JOIN Collection c ON a.AmiiboID = c.AmiiboID
GROUP BY a.AmiiboID
```

[image: Results from above query:]

I have also tried doing this:

```
SELECT a.AmiiboID, a.Name, a.ImageURL, c.Favorited, c.Collected, c.WishList, c.UserID
FROM Amiibo a
LEFT JOIN Collection c ON a.AmiiboID = c.AmiiboID
WHERE c.UserID = 2 OR c.UserID IS NULL
```

Results from above query... Notice AmiiboID 0-4 are missing because they were added by UserID1

[image: Results from above query... Notice AmiiboID 0-4 are missing because they were added by UserID1]

However the problem with this is that it excludes records that were added by another user. So if row 1-5 were entered by userid 1... it would not show row 1-5.

I need to always get ALL records from the Amiibo table AND records from the Collection that have UserID 2 (in this case). And if another user (such as UserID: 1) has added a records, ignore them. I also need there to be no duplicates.

Is this possible?

Thank you,
Travis W.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I just updated it with images

Comment: Using the `left join` to guarantee the retrieval of all the rows of the Amiiibo table is a correct way to to achieve it, as it will fill with null values the columns that belongs to the Collection table that doesn't fullfil the join condition.

Comment: Don't understand quite well, but if you want ALL the records from Amibbo table or not? I guess you need to gather rows from different sources, first get all the amibbo rows, and then gets from collection those rows that refers to UserID2. Then you may combine then using the union operator (union distinct, in your case to discard duplicates).

Comment: Your second comment sounds like what I want! I want all the records from the Amiibo table and then to compare them only against UserID of 2.... the problem I have been running into is that if UserID of 1 enters data, then those are returned in place of the NULLs from Amiibo table,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `c.UserID` check in the `ON` clause when using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.AmiiboID, a.Name, a.ImageURL, c.Favorited, c.Collected, c.WishList, c.UserID
FROM Amiibo a
LEFT JOIN Collection c 
    ON a.AmiiboID = c.AmiiboID
        AND c.UserID = 2
```

There's no need to check for `NULL` in this case.

Comment: Barmar, thank you so much! I've been working on this darn thing for about a day (on and off with distractions) but you saved me so much time. Also thank you for formatting my images in the post. Greatly appreciated! I will mark this as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if something like this works for you...

```
-- Gets all the rows from amiibo "expanded" with the collection
SELECT a.AmiiboID, a.Name, a.ImageURL, c.Favorited, c.Collected, c.WishList, c.UserID
FROM Amiibo a
LEFT JOIN Collection c ON a.AmiiboID = c.AmiiboID

UNION DISTINCT

-- Gets all the rows from collection "expanded" with amiibo that belongs to userId 2 or null
SELECT a.AmiiboID, a.Name, a.ImageURL, c.Favorited, c.Collected, c.WishList, c.UserID
FROM Collection c
LEFT JOIN Amiibo a ON a.AmiiboID = c.AmiiboID
WHERE c.UserID = 2 OR c.UserID IS NULL
```

Comment: That didn't work because it is still returning UserID 1 rows. I need it to always return NULL if UserID doesn't have a record or UserID 2.

Comment: "That didn't work because it is still returning UserID 1 rows" mmmm, let me see...  --> have you tried to add a.UserID <> 1 in the where clause of the correspondant subquey? I see that you already got an answer so there is no underlying need to continue this except to play with mysql a little longer and btw learn :D